How to Correct Sign Issues in Python-LaTeX Code?
This python code
import random

# Generate random values of k and m between 1 and 5
k = random.randint(1, 5)
m = random.randint(1, 5)

# Calculate necessary variables
m_k = m - k
m_1 = m - 1
m_plus = m + 1
k_1 = k - 1
k_plus = k + 1

# Create  with the correct answer marked
answers = [
    f"\\checkmark \\; \\frac{{(n+{m}) !}}{{{k} ! (n+{m_k}) !}}",  # Correct answer
    f"\\frac{{(n+{m_1}) !}}{{{k_1} ! (n+{m_k}) !}}",  # Wrong answer
    f"\\frac{{(n+{m_plus}) !}}{{{k_plus} ! (n+{m_k}) !}}",  # Wrong answer
    f"\\frac{{(n+{m}) !}}{{{k_plus} ! (n+{m_k}) !}}"  # Wrong answer
]

# Mix the answers
random.shuffle(answers)

# Generate text in LaTeX format
latex_output = f"""
After simplifying the expression
$$\\frac{{(n+{m_1}) !}}{{{k} ! (n+{m-k-1}) !}} + \\frac{{(n+{m_1}) !}}{{{k-1}! (n+{m-k})!}}$$
indicate which of the following results is correct:

\\[
\\square \\; {answers[0]} \\quad\\quad \\square \\; {answers[1]} \\quad\\quad \\square \\; {answers[2]} \\quad\\quad \\square \\; {answers[3]}
\\]
"""

print(latex_output)

The code generates a math quiz in LaTeX format with a question and four multiple-choice answers, one of which is correct. It randomly selects values for k and m between 1 and 5, calculates derived variables, creates the answers using factorial expressions, and shuffles them. Finally, it prints the LaTeX-formatted text to present the question and answers.
The fact is that sometimes I obtain results like this:

After simplifying the expression
$$\frac{(n+0) !}{1 ! (n+-1) !} + \frac{(n+0) !}{0! (n+0)!}$$
indicate which of the following results is correct:

\[
\square \; \frac{(n+2) !}{2 ! (n+0) !} \quad\quad \square \; \checkmark \; \frac{(n+1) !}{1 ! (n+0) !} \quad\quad \square \; \frac{(n+1) !}{2 ! (n+0) !} \quad\quad \square \; \frac{(n+0) !}{0 ! (n+0) !}
\]

The things I don't like are: expressions like (n+0)! where I would prefer just n!; and the +- signs that should denote a minus sign for the product of the signs but I can't manage to change. Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

For example, create a variable x = 'n+'+str(m-k-1) if m-k-1==0 else 'n', and replace n+{m-k-1}} with x to handle (n+0)!.

@ScottHunter: Thank you, but I don't think I understood the suggestion and the point where I should add this change you're proposing.

x will be n if m-k-1 is 0; otherwise it will be what you currently get.  Then you replace   n + {m-k-1} with {x} in your definition of latex_output so that it gets used.  Do something similar for each of the other parts that need it & other conditions (like a value being negative).

You can try the following:
import random

# Generate random values of k and m between 1 and 5
k = random.randint(1, 5)
m = random.randint(1, 5)

def f(m):
    if m > 0:
        s = f"(n+{m})!"
    elif m < 0:
        s = f"(n{m})!"
    else:
        s = "n!"
    return s

def g(m, k):
    return rf"\frac{{{f(m)}}}{{{k}!{f(m-k)}}}"

# Create  with the correct answer marked
answers = [
    rf"\blacksquare \; {g(m, k)}",  # Correct answer
    rf"\square \; {g(m-1, k-1)}",  # Wrong answer
    rf"\square \; {g(m+1, k+1)}",  # Wrong answer
    rf"\square \; {g(m, k+1)}"  # Wrong answer
]

# Mix the answers
random.shuffle(answers)
answers = "\\quad\\quad\n".join(answers)

# Generate text in LaTeX format
latex_output = f"""
After simplifying the expression
$$
{g(m-1, k)} + {g(m-1, k-1)}
$$
indicate which of the following results is correct:
$$
{answers} 
$$
"""

